# Primary Menu doesn't show because of w3 cache

Tags: plugins, headers, plugin-w3-total-cache

When I active w3 total cache, my site's primary menu doesn't load. Sometimes when my site takes some time to load only then menu appears.

Comment: what you investigated so far? what options you tried in w3tc?

Comment: Actually I am new to wordpress. I just came to know it's because of W3tc. There are lot of options, I am not sure which I should enable or disable.

Comment: http://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/edu/wordpress/recommended-wordpress-plugins/clearing-cache-in-wordpress

Comment: Of course I have cleared cache many times, its some css file may be that takes time to load. Links are available but menu color is same as header background color, I have  also customized and tried to change the color of both